# "Improper \prevdepth" when using multicols*

Tags: multicol

As I wanted to fill the first column before going to the next one, I was using the environment `\begin{multicols*}\end{multicols*}`. When I compile the following scrip I have the error: `"Improper \prevdepth"`. But it only occurs when I use 3 or more columns. How to solve it?

**Multicols version:**

```
multicol.sty    2015/08/19 v1.8n multicolumn formatting (FMi)
```

**Code:**

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{multicol}% http://ctan.org/pkg/multicol
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols*}{3}    
\lipsum[1-3]
\begin{equation}
aaaa
\end{equation}   
\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

**Gifs proving it:**

[image: Reproducing error]

**Figure 1:** Reproducing Error

[image: Reproducing Work Around]

**Figure 2:** Reproducing work around

Comment: I get no error when running your document

Comment: @DavidCarlisle . when pdfLatex, it shows the error `! Improper \prevdepth.` I'm using Texmaker on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: texmaker and ubuntu are not involved, presumably you have an old version of multicol you could add `\listfiles` to check I tried an old version 1.8p (from texlive 2016) 1.8q (texlive 2017) and 1.9r (texlive 2018) and none of them gave an error.

Comment: I get no error either with TeXLive 2012 (multicol 2011/06/27 v1.7a)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle , I updated the question with more information

Comment: @jfbu , I updated the question with more information

Comment: Thanks for added data, I don't see the bug when using either `multicol 2016/02/08 v1.8o` (TL2015) or `multicol 2014/10/28 v1.8i` (TL2014) and I can't test it with your version of multicol. The example uses very few packages, nevertheless if you add `\listfiles` to preamble you will see in log lines between ``*File List*`` and ``***********``. You could add that info, but as said example contains only lipsum package, article class.

Comment: @jfbu there is no much point in investigation, it was a problem introduced in that version and fixed shortly afterwards. from the change log in tools: 
2016-02-08  Frank Mittelbach  <Frank.Mittelbach@latex-project.org>

 * multicol.dtx: Ensure we are back in vmode before using
        \prevdepth (pr/4448)

Answer (score 4):

After some trial and errors, I found the solution by myself. You must leave a line break on your script between `\end{equation}` and `\end{multicols*}`

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{multicol}% http://ctan.org/pkg/multicol
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols*}{4}    
\lipsum[1-3]
\begin{equation}
aaaa
\end{equation}

\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: can you communicate which multicol version is used? (just check the log file)

Comment: are you sure the problem does not involve some additional package not included in your mwe?

Comment: @VitorAbella please report the version of mutlicol you have. There should be no need to add a blank line so something is really strange and if there is a problem that can be reproduced it should get fixed!  For that I need clear data. Please add \listfiles to your code above and report the result (all of what \listfiles outputs) in the question!

Comment: @FrankMittelbach I updatd the question, anything else you think I should post?

Comment: The first line would have been enough: you use a 3 year old version and the problem was long corrected (which is why nobdoy could reprodue the problem), so the right thing is to update the package.